# If I have N equidistant points within a ball of radius 1, what is the largest possible distance between any two points?

Tags: geometry

I am not trying to generate the points. I would just like to know what the distance between two points are on this ball. Is there a formula for this?

Comment: Presumably this is in $3$ dimensional space.  Then $N$ could be $2$, $3$ or $4$ (well, $0$ or $1$ is rather trivial).  The answers are different in each case.

Comment: Within a ball, or on the surface of the ball?  The title says within, the text seems to say on.  Both problems are hard as $N$ gets larger.

Comment: You could see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014713/how-many-balls-can-be-filled-in-a-large-spherical-shell) and search for packing spheres.  These problems are hard.  You can't have more than $4$ points all equidistant.  You can have each point (roughly) equidistant from its nearest neighbors.

Answer (score 2):

If point $P = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$, and point $Q = (x_2,y_2,z_2)$, you can use the Pythagorean theorem, where the legs of the triangle are the $x$-distances, the $y$-distances and the $z$-distances.

To find the maximum of these distances, you have to write:

$$\max \{\cdots, \cdots, \cdots \}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the sum of the squares of the distances between distinct points.  Then $S \leq n^2$, where equality holds exactly when the centroid of the points is the center of the sphere and each point is on the sphere's surface.  So if you truly have $n$ equidistant points (presumably in $n-1$ dimensions), then the distance between each pair can't be greater than:

$$\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{\binom{n}{2}}}= \sqrt{\frac{2n}{n-1}}.$$